# ThreadLocal in spring web flux

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am new to spring webflux. I am trying to implement the ThreadLocal using spring webflux.

I have a requirement where I need to pass the header from one microservice to another microservice in webclient.

I do not want to pass the header from on service to another service carrying it manually and assigning it in each request.

So thought of using ThreadLocal when I can set it and can access that in webclient call.

I am try to find a sample application where I can refer ThreadLocal with in spring webflux.

Comment: you cant find any examples using it because you cant use it in webflux. If you read the rector documentation you'll understand why.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use ThreadLocal in reactive environment. Webflux (which based on Reactor) is a non blocking framework. It reuses threads so the steps of one reactive pipeline can run in different threads and also multiple requests can use the same thread concurrently - until one waits, another operation will be picked and executed. Imagine if your request puts something into threadlocal and waits - for example - on a db select, another request can override this value and the next pipeline stage of the original request will see that new value belongs to another request. Threadlocal is good for request-per-thread model.

For webflux, you can use contexts. For example put the value into the pipeline in a `WebFilter`, then you can retrieve it in any point of the reactive pipeline:

```
chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(<your data>)
```

In the pipeline (in map/flatmap...)

```
Mono.deferContextual(...)
```

Here is the [link](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) for documentation.

Alternatively you can lift ThreadLocal's value on every operation using Hooks, but this is not a nice and bulletproof solution.

Comment: Thanks zlaval. But how to get my restcontroller request header with filter and pass then to webclient request. Still unclear on that area. I dont what to do explicitly for every request

Comment: you can add `ExchangeFilterFunction`  to the WebClient and in the exchangefunction you can extract the context as mentioned in the comment and add it to the request. `ClientRequest.from(request).header(...)`. Exchange function has a static method called `ofRequestProcessor` so it is easy to implement. This will get the value from the context of the actual pipeline and add it to the header of all webclient requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a support for that. While reading the documentation of Project Reactor, you can find that they enableAutomaticContextPropagation ( https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Hooks.html#enableAutomaticContextPropagation--). 
What this does is that it enables synchronization between the Context from Project Reactor and the use of ThreadLocal. However it requires this library to be used https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/context-propagation?tab=readme-ov-file